# Best way to remove actor from its watcher

Tags: playframework, akka, actor

I write websocket game with play framework and akka. I try implement removing Players from its manager. `Player` actor represent player state with connection.

```java
public class Player extends UntypedActor {

    private final String openId;
    private final ActorRef out;

    public Player(String openId, ActorRef out) {
        this.openId = openId;
        this.out = out;
    }

    @Override
    public void preStart() throws Exception {
        Application.clientManager.tell(
          new ClientsManager.PlayerConnectedMessage(openId, self()), self()
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void postStop() throws Exception {
        //may be tell my id here?
    }
}
```

when it creates, player registers in manager actor from `prestart`. When connection closes, `Player` destroys. I need remove it from manager

```java
public class ClientManager extends UntypedActor {

    private static Map<String, ActorRef> clients = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {

        if (message instanceof PlayerConnectedMessage) {
            final PlayerConnectedMessage connectedMessage = (PlayerConnectedMessage) message;
            context().watch(connectedMessage.client);
            clients.put(
              connectedMessage.id,
              connectedMessage.client
            );
        } else if (message instanceof Terminated) {
            final ActorRef toDelete = ((Terminated) message).actor();
            //How remove, i have only ActorRef
            clients.remove(...);
        }
    }

    public static class PlayerConnectedMessage {
        private final String id;
        private final ActorRef client;

        public PlayerConnectedMessage(String id, ActorRef client) {
            this.id = id;
            this.client = client;
        }
    }   
}
```

In my architecture I want store clients with `Map<String, ActorRef>`, where `String` - id from may logic. Because of this I can't remove client in `Terminated` message - i have only `ActorRef`.

Possible solution: tell `Disconnect` message to manager from `Player`'s `postStop` with it's id and not use `watch` anymore.

Is there a elegant solution with 'watch' way, or solution with `postStop()` also good. I worry about possible clients leaking.